# Cant't build Jenkins latest within Docker

Tags: bash, docker, jenkins, gnupg

******** UPDATE *********

Bash script has no errors, checked with https://www.shellcheck.net/

Adding to the `Dockerfile`the line

`RUN tty | sed -e "s:/dev/::"`

Outputs:

`No tty`

Next line on `Dockerfile` always fails:

`ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh"]`

[image]

I leave an image in order to clarify. In short, I think I need to attach a tty in some way to the batch script, but dunno how to do it.

Thanks

------------------- OLD CONTENT -------------------

I need to update a Jenkins image to 2.138.2. An excerpt of the original `Dockerfile` is as follows:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git curl && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# ...

# Use tini as subreaper in Docker container to adopt zombie processes
COPY tini_pub.gpg ${JENKINS_HOME}/tini_pub.gpg
RUN curl -fsSL https://github.com/krallin/tini/releases/download/${TINI_VERSION}/tini-static-$(dpkg --print-architecture) -o /sbin/tini \
    && curl -fsSL https://github.com/krallin/tini/releases/download/${TINI_VERSION}/tini-static-$(dpkg --print-architecture).asc -o /sbin/tini.asc \
    && gpg --import ${JENKINS_HOME}/tini_pub.gpg \
    && gpg --verify /sbin/tini.asc \
    && rm -rf /sbin/tini.asc /root/.gnupg \

# ...

ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/tini", "--", "/usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh"]
```

Using this `Dockerfile` FAILS due to gpg --import statement now needs to be fixed using `--no-tty` option. So that line remains as follows:

```
&& gpg --no-tty --import ${JENKINS_HOME}/tini_pub.gpg \
```

That's not fine since the execution of `jenkins.sh` now fails in several ways. The code of the script starts as follows:

```
#! /bin/bash -e

: "${JENKINS_WAR:="/usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.sh
```

This script is called from the Dockerfile in this line:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/tini", "--", "/usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh"]
```

But now fails with several errors and seems to be impossible to process the file, nor removing the shebang line, nor removing the '-' or the '-e' option. The rest of the file is not processed fine if we change bash to other shell (not odd) nor removing the -e option (if I do that, the entrypoint does not find the jenkins.sh script).

Sumarizing, I've needed to remove a tty from `gpg` but doing that, I've lost access to bash scripting.

I've checked about the applied workaround, the workaround is described here ( (if I'm right, case is number 8, *gpg might write to the tty at some point*):
    https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2017-April/058162.html

Is there any way to attach a `tty` to the `entrypoint`or having any settings in the script in order to allow this work fine?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to replace `#! /bin/bash -e` with a normal `#! /bin/bash` and in the following line `set -e`?

Comment: The `: "${JENKINS_WAR:="/usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.sh` line in the example code is syntactically incorrect.  Before trying to run `jenkins.sh` with Docker, ensure that it can be run manually.  (You might need to write a test wrapper to set environment variables that it requires.)  Also run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on it to make sure that it has no basic errors.

Comment: Hi @max thanks, but that has the same effect

Comment: Thanks @pjh, ShellCheck verifies the script is right (notice the script is bash) so the problem is about how to run the script attaching a tty

Answer (score 0):

Finally runned on a Linux VM and no problems. Running it on Windows is the problem.